# How do I get data out of the Authorization header and use it in my API? (Lexik JWT)

Tags: angularjs, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle, symfony-2.8, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am in the process of making a SPA (hybrid app) using ionic and AngularJS (1.5.x). I am using Symfony 2.8 for my backoffice and to handle my API.

I wanted to use JWT, and i'm using the Lexik JWT package for it. Everything works fine. When the user logs in, he gets a token that is then saved in the Authorization header. Only users with this token (or rather token in this header) can access the API and do API calls.

The only thing which is unclear to me is how to make it so that the user can only do API calls (Get user information, update only their own posts or such) that concerns their OWN information.

So far I've tried to get the data out of the Authorization header to further on somehow use this token's data (username is in there) to check if it is equal to the user's name who has made this report.

Tried several things such as `getallheaders()`, `$token = $_SERVER['Authorization'];` and other general functions that check the request headers, but everytime I'm getting errors as well.

Am I misunderstanding something or am I missing a step? Am I incorrectly using JWT? Is my reasoning correct that this is how I should do it or is there a more fluent way/logical to do this?

I'm also using FOSRestBundle for my API as well as NelmioCORS, NelmioApiDoc and FOSUSERBundle

Answer (score 2):

When your are behind the firewall provided by the bundle and if the user is correctly logged in, you can get the user object from your controller by calling the methods `getToken()` then `getUser()` of the `security.token_storage` service.
If your controller extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`, you can directly call `$this->getUser()`.

```
<?php

namespace AcmeBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

/**
 * @Route("/api")
 */
class ApiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/hello")
     * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_USER')")
     */
    public function helloAction()
    {
        $token = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
        $if (null !== $token) {
            //$token should be an instance of Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Authentication\Token\JWTUserToken
            $user = $token->getUser();
        }
        // or
        $user = $this->getUser();
        ...
    }
}
```